# Binutils only build "nm"

Tags: gcc, mingw, msys2, binutils, nm

Currently i'm building Binutils with MSYS2 and MinGW on Windows.

Is there a way to only build nm? I cant find documentation on this topic.

I tried to disable some directoires with --disable-DIR but this does not speed up the build process too much and it's still building all Tools like objdump, readelf,...

Comment: Why don't you build the whole binutils? Or why is the prebuilt `nm` not good enough for you?

Comment: We want to invoke the modified main function in nm.c from a MATLAB Mex-file, and for that, we need to be aware of all the dependencies involved in the build process of nm.

Comment: If you need to know the DLLs  the EXE depends on you could use `listpedeps` from https://github.com/brechtsanders/pedeps